# Error with printing min and max from array PHP

Tags: php, printing, max, min

I have a cron that pulls an xml api from a gaming website. 
Cron then tears the data apart and places the information into the proper section of database. The code was written by someone else in 2010 or 2011. I have been trying to bread new life to old script since orignal writer has not kept the code up to date.  When i run my cron i recieve the following error.

key1

Warning: min() [function.min]: Array must contain at least one element in /home3/banumren/public_html/ratter/ratter/cron.php on line 95

Warning: max() [function.max]: Array must contain at least one element in /home3/banumren/public_html/ratter/ratter/cron.php on line 95

[ 0 ] (0 %) - 0 / 0 (beforeRefID: ) 
* [cachedUntil=2014-05-15 01:19:46 (time-api-taken: 2014-05-15 01:04:46]) ]

- wallet.dates = ( to )

The line in question :

```
    <br> * wallet.dates = ( ".$dates1[ min($dates) ]." to ".$dates1[ max($dates) ]." ) \n<br>\n
```

The whole section of code is as follows.

```
    }

$cachedUntil = (string)$wallet_xml->cachedUntil;
$currentTime = (string)$wallet_xml->currentTime;

print "<b>".$corpName." [ $corpId ] ($corpTax %) "." - $add_wallet_rows / $cnt  (beforeRefID: {$beforeRefID}) </b>
<i> <br> * [cachedUntil={$cachedUntil} (time-api-taken: {$currentTime}]) ]  
    <br> * wallet.dates = ( ".$dates1[ min($dates) ]." to ".$dates1[ max($dates) ]." ) \n<br>\n
</i>    ";

$ret = array( 
    'min' => null, //@min( $RefIDs ) , 
    'max' => null, //@max( $RefIDs ) ,  
    'cnt' => count($RefIDs) , 
    'currentTime' => (string)$wallet_xml->currentTime , 
    'cachedUntil' => $cachedUntil ,
);

if( $ret['cnt'] ) {
    $ret['min'] = min( $RefIDs );
    $ret['max'] = max( $RefIDs );
}

return $ret;
```

}

Any ideas as to what could be causing the error? It seems the cron is pulling the api as it has the time values for cached until and current time. The code worked without issues in 2011, Im a novice at php and not sure if there have been any changes to php in the past few years.

could this be the culprit?

```
    $cnt = 0;
$RefIDs = null;
$dates = $dates1 = array();
foreach( (array)@$xml['row'] as $row ) {
    $cnt++;
```

Removed  (array) and no longer receive the error. Now on to another line. at line 180 of 202 so hopefully will have it bug free soon.

Error at line 180 was a missing function from function php. 
[14-May-2014 21:33:50] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function  clear_directory_files_older()
Fixed the error by adding code below to functions.php

```
function clear_directory_files_older($directory,$older_sec,$ext='*') {
$glob = $directory."*.{$ext}";
$removed = 0;

$array = glob( $glob );
foreach( $array as $file ) {
    $filemtime = filemtime($file);
    if( $filemtime < ( time()-$older_sec ) ) {
//      print "\n<br>OLD => ".( $file );    print "<br>".date('r',$filemtime);
        @unlink( $file );
        $removed++;
    } else {
//      print "\n<br>NEW => ".( $file );
    }
}

return $removed;
```

In fixing the new error on 180 the original error returned on line 95

After more searching I walked into the cache folder to have a look around. Seems the issue with the error is the API on the website has changed so much i was not pulling any valid data. After update to the API address cron is now pulling data and updating the cache files correctly. Error no longer occurs.

Comment: `var_dump($RefIDs);` is probably empty

Comment: Given the line that has the error, wouldn't it be $dates that is empty? That's my guess. Inspect it to see.